# Are Java applets worth learning?

Tags: learning, java

I'm on the way of learning Java myself. I find most of texts giving emphasis to Java applets. I got confused about the importance. Is it something widely used?  Do I need to spend more time on it?

Comment: Are you sure those texts are up to date? Generally if I find Java tutorials with an emphasis on applets, they're not from this decade...

Comment: I have mainly three texts,all the examples demonstrating AWT and SWING are based on applets,that's why i asking.

Comment: then you need to get better more modern books, anything that is using AWT for examples is extremely dated. If you book uses `Vector`, `Hashtable`, `Enumerator` or raw `Arrays'` instead of the modern `Collection` class alternatives, throw it out immediately.

Comment: Don't throw them out, but realize they are dated. All those data structures are still important to know about. But do get a book released in the last several years for continued learning

Comment: @rtgibbons:disagree, those books are worthless for learning because they'll teach you to use outdated parts of the standard API and fail to teach you important newer concepts (such as generics). The main thing you need to know about Vector, Hashtable, Enumeration is that you should use ArrayList, HashMap, Iterator instead.

Comment: Those are just structures, the techniques and concepts are still useful. For learning the language, use newer books. But you can still extract useful information from older text, instead of buy a new library of books

Comment: Sorry, Andrew, but I don't find this to be a constructive question. It certainly does not belong here on Programmers, as detailed in the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @Oded Dang!  I thought it would cover 'learning'.  Is there a site?

Comment: I don't believe there is one at this time, though you can check out [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) to see if there is a proposal for one that you can support.

Comment: @Oded Would a change from 'why stop' to 'is it worth' help any?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm afraid I'll have to agree with @Oded. However, this would make for an excellent blog post for the [Programmers community blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/). Would that option interest you?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - It wouldn't. It would then turn to a discussion between people. Every person answering will give their arguments. It is just not a suitable question for a Stack Exchange site. But certainly, a blog post as [Yannis suggests](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196499/why-should-cs-teachers-stop-teaching-applets?noredirect=1#comment380760_196499) could be a great option for exposure and discussion here.

Comment: @YannisRizos  That might fit the bill.  I'll need to rework parts of it..  How do I initiate a blog post?

Comment: I'd [edit] the question to 1) refer to some specific CS course that teaches to deploy applets as part of Java/CS, 2) refer to some other specific course that doesn't do that and 3) re-phrase it roughly as "why is teaching how to deploy applets a part of Java/CS course?" or as "why _this_ course does teach it and _that_ course doesn't"

Comment: @gnat  Unfortunately I am unable to pry the details from most people asking about applets.  They are probably (justifiably) afraid I'll take it up directly with the lecturer. If I can make this a blog post, it will be.  OTOH It looks as though it will be flagged and deleted here, any way it is worded.

Comment: The path of least resistance for most teachers is to adopt the course material provided. This question seems on-topic regarding the construction of such software.

Comment: I thought CS teachers taught Computer Science, not specific gizmos like applets.

Comment: Voted to close: both the question and the self-provided answer are an opinion piece.

Comment: @MetalMikester: They do; some provide more or less assistance in the laboratory part of the course.

Comment: @MetalMikester  *"I thought CS teachers taught Computer Science.."*  Then your apparently not answering many applet questions.  In at least 50% of those questions, it is obvious that the person asking has **no clue** and when it is suggested to use frames instead of applet the reply is *"But the teacher said it has to be an applet.."*  - I personally would tell the teacher to get a grip, but most of the newbies do not have the courage.

Comment: @Oded  I would like to move this to a blog post.  Is there some way that ***I*** can do that, or does it take a moderator?  I've searched the main blog page as well as particular blog posts for a link to the effect 'Start your own blog post' but see nothing.. :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson You should be able to [login to wordpress](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/wp-admin/) with your normal Stack Exchange credentials. Once you do that, ping me in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), so I can give you editor access and take you through the rest of the process.

Comment: ...forgot to mention that I wouldn't mind this to be present _both_ as an answer and as a [Programmers blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/) article

Comment: @gnat  I like your suggestion and will wait to see what others think of your proposal.  Besides the logic of your argument, I must admit it did not take me long to decide I detested the Word Press software.  Now I understand why the code snippets on most Word Press based sites look horrid.  :(  chuckle.. just noticed your latest comment.. ;)

Comment: update: [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/196500/31260) has been reposted to Programmers blog: **[Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/)**

Comment: @gnat  Thanks for the link to blog post.  Now I can stop linking to a closed question!

Answer (score 18):

As one of the most experienced applet developers<sup>1</sup> willing to 
help on public forums (e.g. the Oracle forums or Stack Overflow), it saddens 
me to see new students 'tossed in at the deep end' to learn how to make an 
applet.

The reasons are multiple, but first, I'll look a little at the history of applets
and why applets were ever considered a *good* idea for teaching small, simple projects.

### Applet vs. Frame

The simplest applet is:

```java
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Label;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        add(new Label("Hello World!"));
    }
}
```

Looks simple, right?

But an applet gets a size & position on screen from the HTML that 
loads it.  So an applet also requires a little HTML E.G.

```html
<html>
<body>
<applet 
  code=HelloWorldApplet
  width=400
  height=200>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

This makes the total for a working applet 17 LOC.  Not looking quite 
so simple now.  Worse, many developers think 'any old mark-up will do' 
when that is very much not the case.  Missing opening or closing 
elements make the HTML invalid and how a browser will interpret it 
is anyone's guess.

Compare that to an application that behaves in as smooth a manner:

```java
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Frame;

public class HelloWorldApplication  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.add(new Label("Hello World!"));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So, while it takes just 9 lines of code for the simplest of 
applets (even including the `@Override` notation), while 12 LOC for 
the application doing the same thing, add the HTML and it becomes
17 lines for applet/HTML vs. just 12 LOC for the application.

### AWT vs Swing

Time moves on, and the Swing component toolkit was introduced as
a replacement for AWT.  Nobody uses AWT anymore.  Most Java GUI
developers started using Swing, and those that have used AWT have 
largely forgotten the fine details.

This is relevant to the student in terms of getting help when they 
get stuck.  It does not matter who we are, when approaching new areas
of CS, we all tend to reach for whatever resources might help us 
understand the new technique.  For a student the best resources are 
firstly the text books and class notes, but those typically only 
go so far at explaining, and the rest is from things like the 
[JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), searching the net, or asking for 
clarification on forums.

Those last two are particularly relevant in that:

- There is a slew of extremely poor AWT based code available on the net.
- There may also be some poor Swing based code out there, but usually there
  is a Swing programmer nearby that can point out the deficiencies in it.

Industry uses Swing and that is all that Swing programmers know and 
remember.  AWT is obsolete, and a dead end in career or learning.

So let's now look at the proper way to write a Swing applet & application.
The Java Tutorial warns us that all Swing code should be started and 
updated on the Event Dispatch Thread, which (ironically) is an AWT based Thread.

A simple Swing applet might then be:

```java
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {

        @Override
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                add(new JLabel("Hello World!"));
            }
        };
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(r);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
            ite.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is slightly verbose (25 LOC) for strict clarity, but could be reduced to:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                add(new JLabel("Hello World!"));
            }
        };
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(r);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It could be further shortened (from 20 LOC) by declaring the `Runnable` inside the
`SwingUtilities` method call, but I find that notation to be confusing &
prefer to separate the `Runnable` into a clearly defined instance.

And now the Swing equivalent application, using the same 'short guidelines'.

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.add(new JLabel("Hello World!"));
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Just 18 LOC in total.

Not very much coding to see our simple message on screen, in a 
free floating Swing component.

### Embedded vs. not embedded

#### Security

> Why won't the applet load my input file?

By default, Java applets run in a security sand-box that prohibits many
actions which might be damaging to other applets, the browser or the user's
machine.

While the security sand-box is of great benefit to end-users, it makes 
the life of the developer difficult.  And it has just become that much 
***more*** difficult in Java 7 update 21.

In [Java 7 Update 21 Security Improvements in Detail](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html)
Markus Eisele notes:

> With the introduced changes it is most likely that no end-user is able to run your application when they are either self-signed or unsigned.

While that warning is a little extreme, I agree with the underlying
point being made.  A user (or in this case you, the teacher) will need
to OK some very scary dialogs, and posibly lower the default Java 
security to an unsafe level, before being able to view an applet.

#### Error reporting

> My applet is broken but shows no errors!  Where are they?

The `System.err` stream used for displaying stack traces appears on the
command line (or in the IDE) when running an application.  When a stack 
trace occurs in an applet it is sent to the Java Console, which is (by 
default) not configured to be shown.

#### Class caching

> I changed my applet but the browser shows the same!

Many times I have responded to applet problems where the questioner 
swears they have changed the code & recompiled it, yet the browser is 
still showing the old values.  The solution is relatively simple when 
you know how - flush the class cache from the Java Console.  To someone
learning, it is typically a complete mystery.

#### Embedded conclusion

Those 3 problems alone have probably earned me a quarter of the 
reputation points I've so far earned on this site.  They pose 
huge problems when developing and debugging applets.

But more on Java applets as a web app. component - other cons:

1. Either steal the keyboard focus or do not ever get focus by tabbing around the web page.
2. Need a JRE (and are not compatible with some tablets and all phones)
3. Are not indexed by search engines!
4. At one stage, there was an applet/JRE/browser interaction bug for every fortnight that Java had existed. That is in addition to anything related to security or more generally to JWS apps.
5. A `Frame` gets the right size using `pack()` but an applet has a size forced upon it by the HTML `width` & `height` specified in the `applet` element.
6. ..

### Conclusion

The question really comes down to:

***Are you teaching Java/CS or how to deploy applets?***

If the former, use `JFrame` based applications and side-step all the 
problems that are inherent to an embedded app.  And don't even consider
teaching AWT components - they are obsolete & Swing takes only a few 
more LOC to get something on-screen.

### Author Credentials

1. So who am I?

   - [Top ranked provider of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers) on Stack Overflow for the applet tag.
   - The developer of [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/).
   - Host of many applets on [my site](http://pscode.org/).
2. See also the [blog post](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I actually often wondered why applets are not used so often any more. What are the alternative solutions and why are they considered better?

Comment: @Giorgio  *"What are the alternative solutions.."* 
It depends on what you wish to offer to the user.  Worthy of it's own Q&A. But that might be closed, as well.  ;)

Comment: I find it great to develop and test a desktop application and then deploy it as a web application running in a sand box by just changing a few lines of code. I do not know of other technologies offering this. Also, Java is much more robust than JavaScript so I would rather write a Java applet than a JavaScript application. But I know very little JavaScript to have an authoritative option on this. If you know any any useful reading material on the topic (alternatives to Java applets) could you post a link?

Comment: @Giorgio *"I find it great to develop and test a desktop application and then deploy it as a web application running in a sand box by just changing a few lines of code."*  For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Comment: Thanks, I have already used Java Web Start for an application I have developed a few years ago. I think I used the wrong formulation: I meant I can use the same technology for a web application and for the client of a web application (and for the server, for that matter). Other solutions like JavaScript require a mix of programming languages.

Comment: @Giorgio A JWS desktop app. *can* be a consumer for a web-app.  There are very few situations where an embedded `JApplet` can do something that the free floating app. cannot do. -- OTOH - JS, & the HTML 5 Canvas element can achieve most of what Java would do graphically in a web page.  HTML form fields w/AJAX can act as the basis for a CRUD app for a DB.. JS is a lot less browser-specific than you might think, and there are scripts like jQuery that provide a common interface.  But like I said.  Take it up on a separate question. "How to supply 'X' functionality using HTML/JS?".

Comment: @Giorgio Applet Cons:  1) Java applets either steal the focus or do not get it be tabbing around the web page. 2) Java applets need a JRE (and are not compatible with some tablets and all phones)  3) At one stage, there was an applet/JRE/browser interaction bug for every fortnight that Java had existed.  That is in addition to anything related to security or more generally to JWS apps. 4) A `Frame` gets the right size using `pack()` but an applet has a size forced upon it by the HTML `width` & `height` specified for the `applet`. ..

Comment: Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/155831) if it answered the question!

Comment: It's unfortunate that your answer pits AWT "versus" Swing as though they were completely separate things. All Swing applications use AWT at some point, whether it's for a dimension rectangle or for a color, or for AWT's basic container mechanism. So I disagree when you write "nobody uses AWT anymore", the truth is Swing extends AWT, it does not replace it.

Answer (score 13):

Applets aren't used widely these days, so the knowledge won't be that useful.  That said, there is little in Java that is applet-specific.  It makes no difference if you learn AWT and Swing by writing applets or by writing desktop applications.  It's fairly easy to write an application that will also function as an applet.

The main distinction is that you use a different top-level container for applets than for applications.  Unsigned applets also have some security restrictions, particularly around IO and networking.

Answer (score 3):

Applets are really just a different way of deploying Swing or AWT applications, where you embed the application in a browser-based environment rather than running as a standalone application.

So my advice would be to focus on Swing (AWT is somewhat outdated nowadays...) and if you need to then you can always wrap the same code in an applet later.

I've written Java code that could run either as an applet or a standalone Swing application, you need literally just 10 or so lines of code to support both.....

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to learn GUI development in Java, I would say to stay away from applets and just focus on learning Swing the old-fashioned way.  I don't know all the ins and outs of Applets and it hasn't affected my job negatively.  On the other hand, many games are distributed as applets, as well as the output of [Processing](http://processing.org/).  So it's a good skill to have if you want to distribute your work in an easy to view way on the web, but I wouldn't strive to create anything huge within an applet.

(Do note that it's not impossible to port existing code written for the desktop to run as an applet, which is why I suggest you learn desktop development first.  You'll learn the concepts but without having to jump through the extra hoops of the special applet GUI code, and the browser interactions.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what your intentions are and who your audience is.  Since you are just starting out, and if you do not have a project that requires you to project into the web/browser, I would tinker with Swing and learn how that UI paradigm works.  When the time comes, you can then learn how to wrap that into an Applet and deal with the deployment issues (security, deployment, platform compatibility, etc).  Even if you never use an Applet, or Swing in the future, the core concepts you learn to master Swing (threading, events and listeners, employing a MVC philosophy, basic behavior of UI widgets ....) are useful in almost any UX context.

Answer (score 1):

I would say not, because they're not very widely used.  If you're curious, you might want to take a look at them after you've gotten a good handle on Java.  They're not terribly hard to understand, but I wouldn't include them on my primary list of things to learn.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've noticed, most web pages don't embed Java applets. The programming environment (at least from a web and server perspective) is moving towards easy-to-write and quick to deploy languages and frameworks such as AJAX and .NET.

Flash is another a big reason Java applets have generally moved out of the spotlight. Flash GUI's are incredibly easy to create and most of the behind-the-scenes coding functionality required for interface stuff is already included. I think the only new Java applet I've seen as of late was a specialized stock tracking program built into Think Or Swim.

But what the hell do I know, I write mostly native applications in C++/ASM. I only use the really high level stuff for interfacing with the code I write in those languages.

That being said, while it's useful to know those older Java features, you should get and read more up-to-date material. Java is an evolving language. You will always have to learn new material with each major release. While I mostly code in C++, I do borrow and implement some concepts and features from Java, so I am familiar with the platform.

Here's some project ideas:

- Combined SSH & Telnet Client.
- Chat program.
- A general purpose calculator and solver (something that has
  functionality equivalent to that of a TI-82, not Windows Calc.)
- A Java bytecode decompiler.

---

Feel free to correct me, I'm only 16 and I'm relatively new to the programming world!

Comment: Also, I believe the reason that these books emphasize on coding Java applets is due to the fact that they used to be pretty popular and were the easiest way to deploy integrated programs into a web-page. However newer technologies have come out and older ones have evolved (such as Macromedia -> Flash) and taken over this role.

Answer (score 0):

Generally no, unless you have tried all other GUI platforms/frameworks and itching for something different.

Academically speaking, can provide a different perspective of GUI development whether it is for teaching or demostrations (some might say -ve demo :P ).

Answer (score -5):

if you are building a web-based program handling some very confidential information ( such as banking or financial application), go for applets, the fact that it is not widely used, you can take advantage that to at least get away from the sight of common hackers,
java has a bunch of methods on which you can encrypt everything when you are transmitting data, also the ui itself will require more efforts before you can decompile a *.class file,

just like how popularity of "Windows" make it as an apple of the eye of the virus authors and hackers, 
use non-popular technologies to hold them back

Comment: -1 Security through obscurity is no security at all.